# Inno Setup Set Uninstallable directive based on custom checkbox value

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to know, how to use `Uninstallable` directive, when I don't have tasks or components:

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable:not if IscomponentSelected ('comp1 comp2')
```

I don't have tasks or components created. I only created some checkboxes with a "portable" option, which I want to add uninstallable option, when that one is checked:

```
[Code] 
var 
 Component: TWizardPage; 
 portable,installer: TNewRadioButton;
 Copmp: TLabel; 

function install: Boolean; 
begin 
  Result := installer.Checked; 
end; 

function portab: Boolean; 
begin 
  Result := portable.Checked; 
end; 

procedure InitializeWizard(); 
begin 
 Component :=
   CreateCustomPage(
     wpSelectDir, 'Component Selection',
     'Which types and components would you like to install?'); 

CompPanel := TPanel.Create(WizardForm); 
 with CompPanel do 
 begin 
   Parent := Component.Surface; 
   Left := ScaleX(0); 
   Top := ScaleY(0); 
   Width := ScaleX(417); 
   Height := ScaleY(100); 
   BevelOuter := bvNone; 
  end; 

Copmp := TLabel.Create(WizardForm); 
  with Copmp do 
  begin 
   Parent := CompPanel; 
   Caption := 'Type and components:'; 
   Left := ScaleX(0); 
   Top := ScaleY(5); 
   Width := ScaleX(150); 
   Height := ScaleY(13); 
 end; 

portable := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm); 
 with portable do 
 begin 
   Parent := CompPanel; 
   Left := ScaleX(5); 
   Top := ScaleY(25); 
   Width := ScaleX(200); 
   Height := ScaleY(17); 
   Caption := 'Unpacking'; 
   OnClick:=@CopmpClick; 
 end; 

installer := 
TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm); 
 with installer do 
 begin 
   Parent := CompPanel; 
   Left := ScaleX(5); 
   Top := ScaleY(45); 
   Width := ScaleX(200); 
   Height := ScaleY(17); 
   Caption := 'Install'; 
   OnClick:=@CopmpClick; 
   Checked:=True; 
 end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement a custom function:

```pascal
function IsUninstallable: Boolean;
begin
  Result := installer.Checked;
end;
```

And use it in the `Uninstallable` directive:

```
[Setup]
Uninstallable=IsUninstallable
```

Comment: Can i use more than one Custom function?, Ex: [Setup]
Uninstallable=IsUninstallable1 IsUninstallable2

Comment: Yes, you can. Follow "boolean expression" link from [documentation of `Uninstallable` directive](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable). But why? Implement the logic in the function itself.

Comment: No, it's not. But I cannot tell you what the correct syntax is, because you didn't explain a purpose of the checkboxes. But I would guess that you want this: `Result := installer1.Checked or installer2.Checked or ...;`

Comment: Those TNewRadioButton for installer and portable function are different edition of the  same program.

Comment: That does not explain how those relate the the `Uninstallable` directive.

Comment: I have added some extras TNewRadioButton  [Image](https://i.imgur.com/GyXTiGK.png) But you already gave me the answer Thanks.