# Install files if command-line switch is passed to Inno Setup based installer

Tags: inno-setup

I want to know, if there is a way to add some command line parameters to Inno Setup based installer for `/VERYSILENT` mode, if for example I have theses checks:

```
Source: "{app}\Portable-File.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Check: install1;
Source: "{app}\Installer-File.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 0.0,5.0; Check: porta1;
```

And I have these lines based in my two examples checks:

```
"MyProgram.exe" /VERYSILENT /install1 /EN
"MyProgram.exe" /VERYSILENT /porta1 /EN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `install1` and `porta1` functions like:

```pascal
function HasCommandLineSwitch(Name: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    if CompareText(ParamStr(I), '/' + Name) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

function install1: Boolean;
begin
  Result := HasCommandLineSwitch('install1');
end;

function porta1: Boolean;
begin
  Result := HasCommandLineSwitch('porta1');
end;
```

---

You can actually use the `HasCommandLineSwitch` directly in the `Check` parameter:

```
[Files]
Source: "Portable-File.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: HasCommandLineSwitch('install1')
Source: "Installer-File.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: HasCommandLineSwitch('porta1')
```

*Though I assume that your `install1` and `porta1` function will actually do more than just call `HasCommandLineSwitch`, so this is probably not applicable to you.*

---

*Actually, as I know that you have checkboxes that correspond to `install1` and `porta1`, what you really want to do, is to check those checkboxes, when the installer is starting, if the switches are specified. This way you can use `/install1` and `/porta1` to set default values, even if not used in combination with `/verysilent`. And it will still work even in the `/verysilent` mode, even though the user will actually never see the checkboxes (they are still present, even though not visible)*

```pascal
install1 := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm); 
install1.Checked := HasCommandLineSwitch('install1');

porta1 := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm); 
porta1.Checked := HasCommandLineSwitch('porta1');
```

And you keep your `install1` and `porta1` function to return the state of the checkboxes, as seen in [Inno Setup Set Uninstallable directive based on custom checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46208995/850848).

Comment: when i use for exemple command line /verysilent /porta1, it s creates uninstallation files, it extract all portable files but it gets installed in the system

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. What do you mean by *"but it gets installed in the system"* - What's wrong about that? + How is the behavior different to running an interactive installer and selecting the "porta1" option? - Show us a log file for both scenarios + If you have a problem, we need [mcve].

Comment: This doesnt work when im using /verysilent /porta1: `[Setup]
Uninstallable=IsUninstallable`

Comment: You should do what I have suggested in the last part of my answer. This first part is a generic answer to your *literal* question. But with knowing, what you installers does (and what you failed to explain in your question), I know that the first part won't help. That's why I've included another answer to a question, you *should have asked*.

Comment: Only the last. For all your `installer*` and `portable*` `TNewRadioButton`'s, you have to do that.  Instead of your current `Checked:=True;` and `Checked:=False` for `installer*`; and add the same for `portable*`

Comment: You do not have any `porta1` radio button. In your code it's `portablefree`. But obviously I could not have known that from your question. That's why my answer shows a different identifier. And you should use the syntax within the `with` block anyway, the way you set `Checked:=True`/`False` for the `installerfree` and `installerbusiness` already, as I've suggested you already! + And yes, the `HasCommandLineSwitch` has to be defined above the `InitializeWizard`.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You have to ask a clear question to get a clear answer. Anyway, while your code would work, it';s indeed not correct. Use just `Checked := HasCommandLineSwitch('portablefree');`, not `portablefree.Checked := HasCommandLineSwitch('portablefree');`. The `portablefree.` is implied  by the `with portablefree do`, what's why you have it there. See how you set `Checked` in the `with installerfree do` block.

Comment: All work more or less, portablefree and portablebusiness get installed in windows as installerfree and installerbusiness [Code](https://paste.ee/p/nrEA8)

Comment: For the option that should be selected by default, you should reverse the test: check it if no other is checked. At the end of the `InitalizeWizard` do something like `portablebusiness.Checked := (not portablefree.Checked) and (not installerfree.Checked) and (not installerbusiness.Checked);`